# Where to find Investment home bias data & Historical country weight in World MSCI

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, database

I need the following data and struggles to find it, maybe some of you can help me. Note: I'm a student and in our university ain't Bloomberg nor Reuters.

1. Investment home bias, e.g in 2012 US investors invested about 76% of their equity investment capital in the US market (This is real data). I need this figure for let's say all years between 1990-2015.
2. [Here I can find](https://www.msci.com/resources/factsheets/index_fact_sheet/msci-world-index.pdf) for the latest year (They have only the latest PDF - 2015) US country weight out of the world equity market (Second page, 59.33%). This is true because MSCI World index is considered to be the benchmark for this. How can I find this data for all years between 1990-2015?

The purpose: First number minus the second (for same year, for same country) is the real Investment home bias (for same year, for same country).

Thanks,

Comment: Full MSCI data is only available from Morgan Stanley via providers like Thompson Reuters as an additional option. However, if you have standard excess to Thompson the world scope database can be an alternative

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried searching at Quandl here: https://www.quandl.com/search?query=msci&type=all (Quandl also has flexible pricing plans for individual users, not just companies)